# Xcode live debugging on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, ipad

I have never done any live debugging and unsure of how it works for different languages and platforms.

Basically I want to be able to edit code of my Mac and iPhone applications (iPhone specifically) while they are running and see the changes live.

Is this even possible on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, you can't do it in Xcode. That's because it's compiled and not interpreted, so a new build/deploy has to be performed. Even interpreted or semi-compiled languages have limitations on the extent of changes you can do before requiring a recompile, that is, adding another function to even a VB program will require a new recompile whereas changing a line of code usually doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your running application from Xcode if you did a changes in the code and want to see, how the changed code works.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to know if its possible to make live changes as I know it is possible in some SDKs.

Comment: @JoshKahane, nope. But you can use GDB commands to "live" debug variable values without adding them into NSLog output.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change or add breakpoints and watch variables on-the-fly.
Any change to the code will required a rebuild and redeployment.